# Java - Try/Catch - Access variables in try block if successful

Tags: java, try-catch

Say I have the following block of code somewhere:

```
while(condition){
    try {
        String twoStr= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter two words sep by a space.");
        \\do stuff like splitting and taking an index which may cause out of bound exception
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Sorry your words are terrible.");
     }

\\do stuff with twoStr
```

I cannot access string outside of the try/catch statement, but I don't want to prompt the user to enter another two words in case he messes up and enters a single word. How can I access this value that was initialized in the try block?

Comment: It's a local variable, move the declaration out of try/catch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The string should be defined outside the try/catch statement:

```
while(condition){
    String twoStr = null;

    try {
        twoStr= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter two words sep by a space.");
     } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Sorry your words are terrible.");
     }

     //do stuff with twoStr
```

In this way, both the try/catch statement, as well as the code outside it, will see the variable.  You should read up on [scopes](http://java.about.com/od/s/g/Scope.htm) to get a better understanding of this.

Answer (score 2):

When you define the `string` inside the `try catch` block, it is local to only that block and will not be accessible outside. Define the String variable outside the try catch block like this-

```
while(condition){
String twoStr;
try {
    twoStr= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter two words sep by a space.");
    //do stuff 
 }catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Sorry your name is bad.");
 }
.....
```

Comment: yeah fixed the comment also, thanks :) Now there is no compiler error

Comment: Still won't compile ;) (not for the purpose that the OP wants it for at least...)

Comment: Uh-uh, hint, try using the `twoStr` value after the `try-catch` ;)

Answer (score 2):

Change the scope of `twoStr`

```
while(condition){
String twoStr= null;
    try {
         twoStr= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter two words sep by a space.");
        \\do stuff like splitting and taking an index which may cause out of bound exception
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Sorry your name is bad.");
     }

\\do stuff with twoStr
```

Comment: I could get nit picky and point out that this won't compile ;)

Answer (score 2):

Declare the String outside try catch. If you declare a variable inside the try catch,the scope of the variable is for inside the try catch only So you can not use it outside.

```
 while(condition){
     String twoStr =null;
    try {
        twoStr= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter two words sep by a space.");
       //do stuff like splitting and taking an index which may cause out of bound exception
       }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Sorry your words are terrible.");
     }
```

Comment: @MadProgrammer: LOL :) Next time i will take care while copying OP's code :)

Answer (score 0):

```
String twoStr = null;
while(condition){
     try {
        twoStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter two words sep by a space.");
        \\do stuff like splitting and taking an index which may cause out of bound exception
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Sorry your name is bad.");
     }

\\do stuff with twoStr
```

Answer (score 0):

`twoString` is defined within the context of the `try-catch` block, therefore it can't be accessed out side it, instead you need define the variable before the `try-catch` block...

```
while(condition){
    String twoStr = null;
    try {
        twoStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter two words sep by a space.");
        //do stuff like splitting and taking an index which may cause out of bound exception
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Sorry your name is bad.");
    }

    // You now have access to twoStr
```

Answer (score 0):

Just declare it outside of try-block:

```
String twoStr = null;
while(condition){
    try {
        twoStr= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter two words sep by a space.");
        \\do stuff like splitting and taking an index which may cause out of bound exception
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Sorry your words are terrible.");
     }

\\do stuff with twoStr
```

Comment: I'd add "why" and fix the last line so it would be close to compiling ;)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the string variable `String twoStr` outside the try catch block because the scope of the  variables declared within the try/catch block are not in scope in the containing block, for the same reason that all other variable declarations are local to the scope in which they occur.
You need to declare that variable out of the try catch block.